Error when trying to upgrade project in flutter using VS Code
Error when trying to upgrade project in flutter using VS Code.  Get this error:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
fatal: pack has 13679 unresolved deltas
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Command: git fetch --tags

try running flutter clean and flutter pub get. How many errors you see now?
